# Find $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x) g(x^n) dx$

Tags: limits

Find   $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x) g(x^n) dx$$
Where 
$\;f\in C^0, \quad g\in D^1$

Any hints?

Comment: What does $D^1$ stand for?

Comment: Differentiable once

Comment: Notice that $x^n$ converges to $0$ for all $x\in[0,1)$. Can you utilize this information for your problem? Guessing the answer would be straightforward, while establishing convergence rigorously may be not so immediate, depending on your background.

Comment: Then, what about f(x) ?

Comment: what does $\;f\in C^0$ mean? $f$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Is $g$ differentiable once, with continuous derivative? Note that this allows you to apply integration by parts to the product of $f$ and $g(x^n)$, since $g(x^n)$ is also a once differentiable function. Now deal with the two parts separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need $g$ to be differentiable, it is enough to assume $g \in C[0,1]$ (in fact, all you need is to have $g$ integrable and bounded, and continuous at $0$, as the proof below shows). Then the limit in question equals 
$$
g(0) \int_0^1 f(x) dx,
$$
which we prove below.

Fix $\delta>0$ small and split the integral into $2$ parts, namely
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) g(x^n) dx = \int_0^{1-\delta} + \int_{1-\delta}^1 := I_1 + I_2.
$$

In view of continuity of $f$ and $g$, both functions are bounded on $[0,1]$ and we get
\begin{equation}
|I_2| \leq \delta ||f||_{\infty} ||g||_\infty. \tag{1}
\end{equation}

For $I_1$, observe that $x\in [0,1-\delta]$, hence for any $\varepsilon>0$ small by choosing $N\in \mathbb{N}$ large enough we get
\begin{equation}
|g(x^n) -g(0)| \leq \varepsilon, \ \ \forall x\in[0,1-\delta] \text{ and } \forall n>N, 
\end{equation}
which follows by continuity of $g$ at $0$.

From here, for all $n>N$ we obtain
\begin{equation}
\left| I_1 - g(0) \int_{0}^{1-\delta} f(x) dx \right|  \leq \int_0^{1-\delta} |f(x)| |g(x^n) - g(0)| dx \leq \varepsilon \int_0^1|f(x)| dx. \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Since $\delta>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$ are arbitrary small numbers, from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get the claim.

Comment: thx a miilion, what do you think of the solution of mengdie1982 below?

Comment: you're welcome @Wolfdale; as for your question, I think one can get along without a recourse to dominated convergence theorem (or alike), to get a self-contained treatment for the problem; this is not an opinion, but a mathematical comment.

Comment: Does this mean Lebesgue's theorem is valid only for Lebesgue's integrals?

Comment: @Wolfdale, what theorem are you referring to ?

Comment: Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem

Comment: well, Lebesgue's dom. conv. thm. is for Lebesgue integral indeed, but for general measures  (not necessarily Lebesgue's measure), although I'm not sure what the precise condition on the measure is (can be googled). I'm not sure what the relation of the dominated convergence is to my answer and my comments though.

Comment: Ok thx, this is because I asked your opinion in the solution of  solution of mengdie1982 using this theorem

Comment: @Wolfdale, there is no need to use the dominated convergence theorem (this is the summary of my comments) one can do everything "by hand" here.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)g(x^{n}) \to f(x) g(0)$ almost everywhere and it is uniformly bounded, so teh limit is $g(0)\int_0^{1} f(x) \, dx$ by Bounded Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

We only need to assume that:

- $f$ is integrable over $[0,1]$;
- $g$ is bounded over $[0,1]$ and continuous at $x=0$.

Thus, denote $\phi_n(x)=f(x)g(x^n)$ where $x \in [0,1],n=1,2,\cdots$, and $\max\limits_{0\leq x \leq 1} |g(x)|=M$. It's easy to have that

$$|\phi_n(x)| \leq M\cdot|f(x)|,$$ for $n=1,2,\cdots.$ Moreover, the dominating function $M \cdot|f(x)|$ is obviously integrale over $[0,1].$ Besides, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\phi_n(x)=f(x)g(0),~~~~x \in [0,1].$$

As a result, by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 \phi_n(x){\rm d}x=\int_0^1 f(x)g(0){\rm d}x=g(0)\int_0^1f(x){\rm d}x.$$

Comment: thx a miilion, what do you think of the solution of Hayk above?